# Time series equivalent of hierarchical regression

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis

I'm new to time-series analysis and am currently having some issues understanding which model would be appropriate for what I am looking at. I tried looking at other questions about time-series and [regression equivalents](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311952/hierarchical-regression-in-a-time-series-dataset)  or [hierarchical forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/forecasting-hierarchical-time-series-r-package). I also looked at questions that addressed multiple predictor variables [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195266/time-series-is-time-the-only-independent-variable) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209173/is-it-possible-to-do-a-time-series-analysis-with-more-than-one-explanatory-varia?noredirect=1&lq=1). The question that is most closely related to mine is [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94406/building-a-time-series-model-using-more-than-independent-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I'm still unsure if it's the appropriate one.

To start, I'm not interested in doing any future forecasting (hence the hesitation I had in looking at other questions). Rather, I'm interested in looking at how multiple predictor/independent variables relate to the outcome/dependent variable.

For instance:
I have the outcome variable: **VAR_O**
and I have three predictor variables where **VAR_C** is the control variable and **VAR_P1** and **VAR_P2** are the predictor variables of interest.

In a *cross-sectional analysis*, I would use a hierarchical regression where block 1 consists of VAR_C and VAR_P1 to 'predict' VAR_O. The second block would consist of VAR_C, VAR_P1, and VAR_P2 and I would examine the change in R sq that resulted from the addition of VAR_P2.

However, suppose that my data is longitudinal (with the unit of analysis being years or months); since the observations/cases are not independent, my understanding is that I can't use regression and that I should use time-series analysis.

So my questions are:

1) What would be the appropriate time-series analysis to examine whether changes in VAR_P1 and VAR_P2 across time predict changes in VAR_O, while controlling for VAR_C? (in other words, just doing the same as a cross-sectional hierarchical regression but with longitudinal data?)

2) Also, what if there are seasonal trends (in the case of months)
3) or there aren't (in the case of years)?